# Flipping Coins and Rolling Dice

Tags: python

I have to write a program that flips coins until it gets to heads and when it gets to heads it has to roll a dice the amount of flips it took to get to heads. I am struggling and don't really know how to do this i am an amateur at python and struggle with it greatly.

```
import random
def headcount(n):
    heads=0
    tails=0
    for amount in range(n):
        flip= random.randint(0,1)
        if (flip==0):
            print("heads")
```

What my problem is, is im not sure how to keep it going, i get to this point and get stuck. Just looking for ideas, not trying to have everyone write code for me, sorry.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Excellent. Do you have a question?

Comment: i have: import random
def headcount(n):
    heads=0
    tails=0
    for amount in range(n):
        flip= random.randint(0,1)
        if (flip==0):
            print("heads")

Comment: Put that in your question and explain specifically what is not working about that code.

Comment: You should ask your professor or TA for guidance. If you have *specific* questions, you can ask them here, but please don't try to use this as a code-writing service, or a tutoring service for that matter. That is not the purpose of StackOverflow. That being said, on-topic and well-formed questions are OK even if they are related to classwork.

Answer (score 2):

Let's write a function for each action, flipping a coin and rolling a die

```
def flip_coin():
    if random.randint(0, 1): #Here I am taking advantage of the fact that 0 is considered false
        return "Heads"
    else:
        return "Tails"

def roll_die():
    return random.randint(1, 6)
```

Now let's get into the code.  First we'll flip a coin and set our counter to one.  Then we will continue flipping coins and incrementing our counter until we see `Heads`.  Then we will roll that many dice

```
result = flip_coin()
print(result)
count = 1
while result == "Tails":
    result = flip_coin()
    print(result)
    count += 1
for i in range(count):
    print(roll_die())
```